# Separar tag <script> por ponto e vírgula

Tags: javascript, regex

Tenho uma variável que pode armazenar ***texto simples*** e as tags `<script>` e `<img>`, delimitadas por `(';')`. Para separar as informações, uso o método `split(';')`. Funciona bem para textos e `<img>`, porém, com `<script>` dá erro (`SyntaxError: unterminated string literal`), imagino que devido aos vários pontos e vírgulas dentro dela. Gostaria de uma solução que funcionasse tanto para ***texto*** e `<img>`, quanto para `<script>`.

```
var test = 'texto1; texto2'; // Sem problema
var test = '<img src="imagem.jpg" />; <img src="imagem2.jpg" />'; // Sem problema
var test = '<script type="text/javascript">var a = "valor1";</script>; <script type="text/javascript">var b = "valor2";</script>'; // Com problema
console.log(test.split(';'));
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

O problema não está nos `;` mas sim no fato de que os navegadores fazem o *parse* da string `<script>` de forma abstrata, procurando logo por uma `</script>`.

Como tens no conteúdo da variável `test` o texto `<script>`, recebes o erro do navegador ao fazer o *parse* desse código:

```
SyntaxError: unterminated string literal  
var test = '<script type="text/javascript">var a = "valor1";  
-----------⤴
```

Ou seja, o código nem chega a ser executado porque ao ser feito o *parse* do documento, ocorre logo um erro de *syntax*.

---

O teu código para funcionar corretamente precisa de ser adaptado para:

```
var test1 = 'texto1; texto2';
console.log(test1.split('; '));

var test2 = '<img src="imagem.jpg" />; <img src="imagem2.jpg" />';
console.log(test2.split('; '));

var test3 = '&#60;script type="text/javascript">var a = "valor1";&#60;/script>; &#60;script type="text/javascript">var b = "valor2";&#60;/script>';
console.log(test3.split('; '));
```

Ver exemplo no [**JSFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/zuul/7dmmsxo7/).

1. O `split()` deve ficar com `;`  para apanhar a separação das tags e não os `;` dentro das mesmas.

   <sup>Dependendo da complexidade do código dentro das tags de *script*, o `split()` pode precisar de ajustes ao seu parâmetro.</sup>
2. O `<` deve ser convertido na entidade `&#60;` para que o navegador não leia esse texto como a abertura de uma tag de *script*.

**Nota:**
Também podes fazer escape da seguinte forma: `<\/script>` ao invés de usares HTML Entities.

Answer (score 3):

Se seu script estiver embutido na página (i.e. `<script type="text/javascript"> código </script>`), veja [a resposta do Zuul](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/55257/215) para uma possível solução (outra seria mover seu script para um arquivo externo, que no meu entendimento não estaria sujeito a esse problema).

Quanto à questão dos pontos-e-vírgulas dentro dos scripts, na ausência de uma solução mais completa (i.e. um *parse* apropriado do conteúdo) o que você pode fazer é - depois de separar em pedaços - juntar de novo aqueles pedaços que deveriam estar juntos. Exemplo:

```js
var test = 'texto1;texto2;<script type="text/javascript">var a = "valor1";<\/script>; <script type="text/javascript">var b = "valor2";var c = "valor3";<\/script>;<img src="imagem.jpg" />; <img src="imagem2.jpg" />';

var pedacos = test.split(';');
var resultado = [];
for ( var i = 0 ; i < pedacos.length ; i++ ) {
    var proximo = pedacos[i];
    while ( proximo.indexOf("<script") >= 0 && proximo.indexOf("</script") < 0 )
        proximo += ';' + pedacos[++i];
    resultado.push(proximo);
}

// Só para visualização
document.querySelector("body").innerHTML += "<ul>";
for ( var i = 0 ; i < resultado.length ; i++ )
    document.querySelector("body").innerHTML += "<li>" + resultado[i].replace(/</g, "&lt;") + "</li>";
document.querySelector("body").innerHTML += "</ul>";
```

Comment: [Como se forma o plural da palavra ponto-e-vírgula?](http://www.ciberduvidas.com/pergunta.php?id=27946) :)